# How to fix Eclipse and Caja color in Linux Mint Mate?

Tags: eclipse, gtk, colors

I started using **Eclipse IDE** with Linux Mint.
I have darkened Ambiance theme and Eclipse looks extremely ugly and painful to eyes. And it seems I cannot change that white color of file browser background and Eclipse sides...
[image]

I have tried to install different theme - Nodoka Midnight. Istalled it via Synaptic. No help - some error and that white color is still there.
[image]

I have tried to use **gnome-color-chooser**, but I cannot find an option to change. Many people ask how to change color of tooltips, but they are just fine for me.

Internal Eclipse themes affect only it`s text editor.
I have restarted Eclipse and Linux - no change. But I feel that color setting is somewhere near.

How do I change that white color and where?

Comment: I will repeat it here.
The problem is solved. In both applications colors are changed inside their own settings, but in not obvious places.
Caja: Edit -> Backgrounds and emblems -> Colors
Eclipse: Window -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance (Not color theme!)
That`s it.

P.S. If there was an solution on black on black and white on white in browser, satisfaction would be complete.